# Why is "this.connection" undefined when attempting two-way binding with alpine.js x-model directive

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I'm building a very basic Guacamole client for a proof-of-concept, I'm using Alpine.js to bind the form input elements containing the connection values to the corresponding `this.connection` data object of the component, however when it comes to using the properties within my `connect()` method, `this.connection` is undefined. I am expecting it to contain values assigned to my connection properties (scheme, hostname, port, username and password).

The x-data object method:

```js
function manage() {
    return {
        connection: {
            scheme: '',
            hostname: '',
            port: '',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },

        connect: () => {
            console.debug(this.connection) // <--- undefined
            let query = gc.generateConnectionQueryString(this.connection)

            gc.connect({
                websocketUrl: 'url-here',
                connectionQueryString: query
            })
        }
    };
}
```

The component HTML:

```
<div id="app" x-data="manage()">
    <div class="container mb-12">
        <form action="#" method="post" @submit.prevent="connect()">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <label for="scheme">Protocol</label>
                </div>
                <div class="data">
                    <input type="text" id="scheme" name="scheme" x-model="connection.scheme" placeholder="e.g. rdp, ssh, vnc">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <label for="hostname">Hostname</label>
                </div>
                <div class="data">
                    <input type="text" id="hostname" name="hostname" x-model="connection.hostname" placeholder="e.g. myserver.net, 192.168.1.242">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <label for="port">Port</label>
                </div>
                <div class="data">
                    <input type="text" id="port" name="port" x-model="connection.port" placeholder="e.g. 5901">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="data">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" x-model="connection.username" placeholder="username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="label">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="data">
                    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" x-model="connection.password" placeholder="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" class="bg-blue" value="Connect">
                <button type="button" class="ml-6 bg-red">Disconnect</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport" id="viewport">
        <div tabindex="0" class="display" id="display"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and how I can solve my issue of properties being undefined? I've tried looking for answers at the Alpine.js Github repo but I couldn't find what I was looking for, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want `this.connection` to be? The connection object above (with scheme, hostname, port, etc.)?

Comment: @Xge yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the object you're returning in the object itself.

First create a variable in the function, then return it and get it without `this`:

```js
function manage() {

 // Create variable before returning
 let connection = {
      scheme: '',
      hostname: '',
      port: '',
      username: '',
      password: ''
 }

 return {
  connection, // (same as connection: connection)
  connect: () => {

   console.debug(connection); // Will return the connection you defined in the variable

   // YOUR CODE  

  }
 }

}
```